# Стоит ли создавать под каждую ОС ветку git для игры на UNITY

Tags: unity3d, ios, github

Планируется три - `Harmony`, `iOS`, `Android`

Изначально создался проект на `Android`, были две ветки под ***dev*** и ***release***.

Стоит ли создавать другие ветки под каждую ОС, и хранить там версии игр, и обновлять каждую ветку, будет ли удобно работать таким методом? К примеру одинаковый функционал (геймплей) будет ли удобно переносится мерджем?

> *(**dev_android**, **release_android** || **dev_harmony**, **release_harmony** || **dev_iOS**, **release_iOS**)*

Или эффективнее работать в одной паре веток с кодом для всех платформ?

Вопрос к тому что для `iOS` и `Harmony`, `Google Services` и все вытекающие будут лишними. И нагружают проект не используемыми ресурсами

Comment: Зависит от того: 1) одинаковый ли каденс релизов для всех платформ (н-р, одинаково ли будут добавлять фичи во все или в разное время). Будет сложно релизить что-то для одной платформы с куском недописаного кода в том же бранче для другой. 2) каков объем общего кода для платформ. Если много общего, то лучше минимизировать кол-во веток

Comment: @Hardoman, каденс равномерный на все платформы, общего больше 75%, от моего комментария складывается ответ что стоит держать минимальное кол-во веток и уместить все платформы в один код, у меня основной вопрос как будет правильнее? К примеру как это реализовывают профессионалы, при равномерной каденсе, и больше 50% общего кода, просто когда смотришь на код и видишь повсюду #if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_EDITOR и подобные ... смотриться совсем не удобно да и если код скрыт не в UNITY_EDITOR он ещё теряет подсветку и их не видно в ссылках, они просто становятся комментарием визуально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не стоит использовать разные ветки под каждую ОС а также не используйте #if. Вместо этого попробуйте [Сборки](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html). Поместите общий код для всех платформ в одну сборку а специфичный для конкретных платформ в другие, установите в инспекторе сборки под какие платформы компилировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разбираюсь в теме, от того что узнал, получается для разных платформ стоит создавать разные скрипты по задачи данной платформы и помещать их в необходимые сборки

Comment: Да, а также использовать другую сборку для общих скриптов

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ помагает двигаться вперёд увереннее, уже изучаю данную тему, я подожду ещё пару дней на получение ещё мнений на этот счёт, и выберу лучший ответ